# Find Min of function $x+\frac{2}{x}$ for x>0 with following solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, maxima-minima

I want to find Minimum of function $x+\frac{2}{x}$ for $x>0$ with following solution. My problem is how can we say we found the answer with following solution.
Solution:

Let Minimum be something like c. We have:

$x+\frac{2}{x} \ge c \to \frac{x^2+2}{x} \ge c \to x^2 + 2 \ge cx \to x^2 -cx +2 \ge 0 $

So $\Delta \le 0$ because the quadratic must not have two solutions so it will be only positive or zero. So:

$\Delta = c^2 - 8 \le 0 \to c^2 \le 8 \to -2\sqrt{2} \le c \le +2\sqrt{2}$

My question is how can we say with following solution that the minimum  of $x+\frac{x}{2}$ must be $+2\sqrt{2}$? We find the maximum of $c$, How can we say that maximum is minimum of function? Is it a valid solution?

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x+\frac2x>0$, we can assume that $x+\frac2x$ has a non-negative lower bound $c$ for $x>0$, that is:
$$\exists c\ge 0\;\forall x>0\;x+\frac2x\ge c$$

This inequality is equivalent to
$$\exists c\ge 0\;\forall x>0\;x^2-cx+2\ge 0$$

The polynomial $x^2-cx+2$ has no negative root, because the sum of the roots is $c(\ge 0)$ and their product is $2$.

So, under the assumption $x^2-cx+2\ge0\;\forall x>0$, the polynomial has one root or no root. As you has pointed, that fact is equivalent to this:
$$c^2-8\le 0$$ 
or (remember that $c\ge 0$)
$$0\le c\le 2\sqrt 2$$

To sum up:

> The real number $c$ is a lower bound for $\{x+\frac2x:x>0\}$ if and only if $0\le c\le 2\sqrt 2$.

This means that $c$ is the greatest lower bound for $x+\frac 2x$. Since
$$\sqrt 2+\frac2{\sqrt 2}=2\sqrt 2$$
this lower bound is reached, and thus, it is the minimum that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using $AM-GM$ inequality, we have(since $x>0$)

$$ x + \frac{2}{x} \geq 2 \sqrt{ x \cdot \frac{2}{x} } = 2 \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Hi. I know the answer is $2sqrt{2}$ I want to know how can we say that with the solution written above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the original inequality $$x + \frac{2}{x} \ge c$$ after you have concluded that $$-2\sqrt{2} \le c \le 2\sqrt{2}.$$  If we suppose $c = 0$, then is the original inequality true?  Yes:  $x + 2/x \ge 0$ is a true statement for $x > 0$.  Indeed, any value of $c$ in the interval you obtained, when substituted into the first inequality, results in a true statement, *by construction*.  But all of the inequalities resulting from choosing $c < 2 \sqrt{2}$ are **looser** than the inequality resulting from choosing $c = 2 \sqrt{2}$, in the sense that for any $c' < 2 \sqrt{2}$, we trivially have $$x + \frac{2}{x} \ge 2 \sqrt{2} > c',$$ hence $c = 2 \sqrt{2}$ results in the tightest inequality of the set of choices we can make.

The only missing part is to show that equality can be attained for this choice of $c$ thus guaranteeing that the inequality is strict, and of course, this occurs when $x = 2/x = \sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\ge 0$
$$ax+\frac{b}{x} \ge c $$
$$ax^2-cx+b \ge 0$$
Since the quadratic is always greater than equal to zero, so the discriminant $D \le 0$
$$c^2-4ab\le 0$$
As we can we observe that function is decreasing in $(0,\sqrt {2})$ and increasing in $[\sqrt {2},\infty)$ this show that the point of  minima must exists at $ \sqrt {2}$

Comment: How did you get the last paragraph? I know we can get this by plotting the function but i want to get it without using graphs. How did you get that with $c^2 - 4ab /le 0$?

Comment: How did you get the last paragraph? I know we can get this by plotting the function but i want to get it without using graphs. How did you get that with c2−4ab/le0c2−4ab \le 0$?

Comment: How did you get the last paragraph? I know we can get this by plotting the function but i want to get it without using graphs. How did you get that with $c2−4ab/le0c2−4ab\le0$ ? Sorry for wrong MathJax using in above comments.

Comment: @titansarus You can delete the wrong comments(Mathjax).

Comment: I know this is discriminant. I want to know how did you get the (0,sqrt(2)) and ... in last paragraph.

Comment: @titansarus I found the interval in which function is decreasing and increasing .For decreasing $f'(x)\le 0$ and for increasing $f'(x)\ge 0$

Comment: The Original problem indicated that you must solve it without using Differential and Integral (calculus) strategies. So I made my solution which you can see in context of question and I want to know is it valid or not?

Comment: @titansarus Indeed ,It is valid .

Comment: @titansarus I think you should make some edits in your question and  make it clear what you want to know .